# Equivalent definition

Tags: general-topology

So when I was reading Topology by Munkres, the definition of a basis for a topology is:

1. For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.
2. If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $x \in B_3 \subset B_{1} \cap B_{2}$.

But the definition I learned from class was:

A collection $\mathcal B$ is called a basis for a topology if:

1. $\bigcup\limits_{B\in\mathcal B} B =X$
2. $\forall B_1, B_2$ are basis elements, $B_1 \cap B_2$ is a union of elements of the basis.

How to see that the two definitions are equivalent? Especially the second part.

Comment: If you are happy with (1) iff (1'), then exactly the same reasoning will apply to (2) iff (2'). Both are simply rephrasing what it means for one set to be the union of a family of sets.

Answer (score 2):

Both equivalences use the same logic: you want to show that a given set is a union of basis elements, so you write it as a union of basis elements corresponding to points.

For the first equivalence: Suppose for each $x\in X$ there is a basis element $B_x\ni x$. Then $X=\bigcup_x B_x$.

For the second equivalence, it's similar: if for each $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ we have a basis element $B_x$ with $x\in B_x\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$, do you see how to write $B_1\cap B_2$ as a union of basis elements?

Comment: For the set-theory purists: There's an implicit use of choice in what I write above, where I assume we actually have a map $x\mapsto B_x$. This is of course unnecessary.

Comment: $B_x \in B_1 \cap B_2 \Rightarrow \cup B_x \in B_1 \cap B_2 \Rightarrow \cup B_x = B_1 \cap B_2$

Comment: @ZoZO You've got the right idea - $B_1\cap B_2$ is indeed $\bigcup_{x\in B_1\cap B_2} B_x$ - but what you've written is a bit garbled. You mean "$\subseteq$" not "$\in$" in the first two implicants, and you need to say a brief word about why "$\bigcup B_x\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$" implies "$\bigcup B_x=B_1\cap B_2$." (Also you should specify what the unions are taken over - all $x$ in $X$? all $x$ in $B_1\cap B_2$?)

Comment: Because $B_1 \cap B_2 \subset \bigcup B_x$ since $\bigcup B_x$ is the union of all $B_x$, so the equality holds?